# How to run multiple threads in tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Let's say if we write something like this:

```
import threading
Button(root, command=threading.Thread(target=func1).start)
```

Now if we click the button once then it will be fine but we try to **click the button again** then a error comes ***"Thread can only be executed once"***.

So, how to avoid this

Comment: Use `lambda` instead: `command=lambda: threading.Thread(...).start()`.

Comment: If I am using this code the button is not even firing the command

Comment: Note that it should be `start()` when you use `lambda`.

Comment: My suggestion of using `lambda` should work, see example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Answer::
As you clarified it in comments, you can redefine the `Button` every time it is clicked allowing it to accept multiple clicks and thus creating multiple `threads` as required.
You could do that inside the target `func1()` or `callback` function for `threading.Thread` object.

A working example example would be like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def func1():
    theButton.configure(command=threading.Thread(target=func1).start)
    print('Do everything else here')

root = tk.Tk()
theButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=threading.Thread(target=func1).start)
theButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: Thanks to CoolCloud for suggesting a better way to configure the Button inside callback `func1()`.

Comment: Does this actually allow the user to actually execute the function twice?

Comment: I don't want that button get disabled. I want that the user can click the button multiple times.

Comment: @Vasu I see. So a single button, allowing multiple clicks, and each time a click happens - run the thread. If that is right, see the edited answer.

Comment: @CoolCloud Somehow I didn't notice that requirement from OP in the title in the first go :| (sometimes I do be crazy xD) but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ummmm, easier way `theButton.config(command=threading.Thread(target=func1).start)`  and get rid of the `grid(..)` too

Comment: @CoolCloud Oh yeah. Edited to reflect the same.

Comment: This is not working.. I am getting the same error that **"Threads can only be executed once"** if I try to click the button twice

Comment: @Vasu I just rechecked my code and it works totally perfect. Have a look at these pictures below of what happens when I execute the code. [The Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tLZYH3RWbnKjUNou_6FsX4Fn7sMRkkiY/view?usp=sharing) .

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create one instance of `threading.Thread()` and pass its `start` method to `command` option of the button.  You should create new instance whenever the button is clicked by using `lambda`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

def func1():
    print('Hello')

tk.Button(root, text='Go', command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=func1).start()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if i am using lambda then I am not able to click the button even